# Swift - NSMutableAttributedString changes all text in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

**Download an example I have created**

[Example Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kialnssksvcxq3/MyTextViewToolbar.zip?dl=0)

I am adding a link to my UITextView like this:

```
 let systemFont = self.text.font!
 let linkAttributes = [
          NSFontAttributeName : systemFont,
          NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: alertController.textFields![0].text!)!] as [String : Any]

 let myAttributes2 = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: customGreen]

 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(urlName)")

 // Set the 'click here' substring to be the link
 attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, urlName.characters.count))//(0, urlName.characters.count))

 self.text.linkTextAttributes = myAttributes2
 self.text.textStorage.insert(attributedString, at: self.text.selectedRange.location)

 let cursor = NSRange(location: self.text.selectedRange.location + "\(urlName)".characters.count, length: 0)
 self.text.selectedRange = cursor
 // self.text.font = systemFont
```

But after inserting it, it changes all the current text in the UITextView to the same font.

So for example if I have some text that is Bold and some more text that is Italic, after I add the url(which is system font) it resets all the bold/italic text to the system font....

If anyone knows how to keep the current font of the previous text I'd really appreciate the help.

For any further explanation just drop a comment below!

Many thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

**Update**

I am changing the text here in textDidChange

```
  if text == " " 
  {
       //      let systemFont = self.text.font!
       //    let linkAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName : systemFont]
       let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black, NSFontAttributeName: self.text.font!] as [String : Any]

       let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
       self.text.textStorage.insert(attributedString, at: range.location)
       let cursor = NSRange(location: self.text.selectedRange.location+1, length: 0)
       textView.selectedRange = cursor
       return false
 }
```

I have that so after adding the URL I make a space and reset the font so I don't continue typing as a URL link...Probably the problem but when I type normal and don't set a url link the text doesn't changing while make a space...

Comment: Your code seems to be ok, can you elaborate more please?

Comment: @J.Koush Well, thats what I thought too. Basically this is my UITextView: **This is some bold text** and  __This is some italic text__ (So far too different types of fonts) www.Google.com(this is system font text. After adding this link it sets the previous bold text and italic text to be ||System font text(normal text like here.)||  and obviously I want to keep the previous bold text and italic text and just want the link to be system font text.). not sure if that helps anymore... I'll try and get a example done later if you dont understand?

Comment: did you uncomment the last line `// self.text.font = systemFont`, because it's working on my app, make sure you're not changing the font on the UITextView somewhere else.

Comment: @J.Koush check my update

Comment: @Jack try my answer

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya what aswer

Comment: my answer is in objective c so just remove it if you want and you convert it into swift then i added it again

Answer (score 4):

```
let urlName = "google"

@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {

   let systemFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
   let linkAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName : systemFont,
        NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")!] as [String : Any]

   let myAttributes2 = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green]

   let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(urlName)")

   attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, urlName.characters.count))//(0, urlName.characters.count))

   self.text.linkTextAttributes = myAttributes2
   self.text.textStorage.insert(attributedString, at: self.text.selectedRange.location)

   let cursor = NSRange(location: self.text.selectedRange.location + "\(urlName)".characters.count, length: 0) 
   self.text.selectedRange = cursor
}
```

This is how you should update the textView if you want to add text programmatically.
Do not use the textViewDidChange(_:) delegate method in this situation.

**UPDATE**

I've downloaded your code from dropbox and made some changes to it.
so here I'm changing the textView text in viewDidLoad() for example.
I've created two constants in order to use them again in the code, `fontAttr` is the original font with the name and size and `fontColorAttrBlue` is the original font color.

```
let fontAttr = UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Bold", size: 20)
let fontColorAttrBlue = UIColor.blue

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Hello World, How are you?", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : fontAttr!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: fontColorAttrBlue ])
    self.textView.delegate = self // you can set the delegate from the storyboard.
    self.textView.attributedText = attrString
}
```

And I've deleted this line of code `self.textView.font = systemFont` from `webLink(_ sender: AnyObject)` action method, so that it wouldn't change the font of the textView.

And lastly in `textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText:)` method instead of checking if the user has entered `" "` String I'm checking if the user has entered any String and reusing the font attributes that I created in the beginning, so that if the user enters any kind of text after the link it would be the original text and not the one assigned for the like text.

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text.characters.count > 0 {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : self.fontAttr!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.fontColorAttrBlue])
        self.textView.textStorage.insert(attributedString, at: range.location)
        let cursor = NSRange(location: self.textView.selectedRange.location+1, length: 0)
        textView.selectedRange = cursor
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats my text, and I am not adding it when I launch my app. I add the link when I press a button.

Comment: @Jack I have created a constant urlName, and inserted the code in an IBAction so that we a user presses a button it will get called and the constant urlName will be added to the end of the UITextView text.

Comment: and what happens when you start typing in the textview right after the link, the text remains a link

Comment: Check it out thanks, but still doesn't work... I'll explain why later